# variable substitution

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, perl, zsh

I found this on shell script, in variable substitution option using cap symbols
can anyone explain the logic of this nf=${f:gs^__^/^}

```
for f in  notes__* books__*; do
    nf=${f:gs^__^/^}
    perl -p -e $f > /home/bob/$nf
  done
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Is this bash or zsh?

Comment: It is in zsh script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tagged your question both `bash` and `zsh`, however AFAIK the `:s` syntax is only supported in `zsh` (borrowed from `csh`). The bash equivalent would be `${f//__/\/}` - which is also supported in zsh (and borrowed from `ksh`).

`:gs` introduces a **g**lobal **s**ubstitution inside the parameter expansion. `^` is an arbitrary (user-supplied) delimiter - the usual choice would be `/` but in this case it appears the replacement text is `/` so `^` is chosen instead. So given

```
f=notes__foo__bar
```

`${f:gs^__^/^}` globally replaces `__` with `/`:

```
 % echo ${f:gs^__^/^}
notes/foo/bar
```

Refer to `man zshexpn` for further details.

Comment: Thank you so much guys